# Flutter launch screen in android transitions from black titlebar to white

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app with this `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here is my lauch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The problem is that when the app starts, I see this screen first(see the color of title bar)

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2(Ignore the switch like icon)]

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:icon="@mipmap/myicon"
        android:label="My App">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="assets.audio.player.notification.icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_music_custom" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I just wonder how do I prevent the titlebar color from changing?

Flutter version:  1.19.0-2.0.pre

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information about your app, but as I can see...

1.- You are declaring your NormalTheme but you are not using it. Try to add this inside your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest >
    <application>
        <activity
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2.- The second screen shows your app initialized, to see the correct app title, use Scaffold (and try to add an AppBar if you prefer).

3.- You can also change the status bar color with this:

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.blue),
  );
```

Hope it helps.